# eclipse: android emulator running, but program not starting

Tags: android, eclipse

I am experimenting with android and I have installed everything like explained on android.com (jdk, eclipse, sdk, adt). I created a phone (2.2).
I have created a hi, world app.
When I try to debug or run the app as an android program, it does not get launched.
The emulator gets launched and I can browse the phone, but the app is not starting.

Logcat is showing:

> [2011-10-27 15:01:42 - hiAndroid] ------------------------------
>
> [2011-10-27 15:01:42 - hiAndroid] Android Launch!
>
> [2011-10-27 15:01:42 - hiAndroid] adb is running normally.
>
> [2011-10-27 15:01:42 - hiAndroid] Performing org.example.hi.Hi activity launch
>
> [2011-10-27 15:01:42 - hiAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android2.2'
>
> [2011-10-27 15:01:42 - hiAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android2.2'

I have tried installing the same programs in a virtual machine running winXP 32-bit (i use win7 64) and on this machine everything seems to be working s
Anyone any ideas?

Comment: close the current emulator and launch a new one.

Comment: Could you please mark a response as the correct answer, thanks

Comment: @YashwanthKumar I came across the same problem, closing the current emulator and lauching a new one does not work. The problem is the started emulator is disconnected from the adb server, only when you restart the adb server as Josephus Villarey has answered, the emulator will work. Otherwise launching a new emulator results in the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try restarting your adb
open up your console and type in

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try restarting ADB from the command line/shell. Try

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

You can also check that the device is being picked up correctly by entering

```
adb devices
```

If that doesn't work restart Eclipse (if that's what your using) and possibly your computer. I've had some weird issues relating to the ADB in the past and a restart has usually fixed it.

Note: if you haven't added adb to your path is located in your *android-sdk-install/platform-tools/* folder

Comment: wonderful, thanks guys! restarting adb from a command line window did the trick.